# Children's book - girl's mother sent to jail for theft, dog and girl on cover

Tags: identification-request

I read a book to my cousin two years ago which I would like to revisit. It was a book about a girl whose mother goes to jail after being accused of stealing drugs from the pharmacy she worked at.

I think the girl's name was Lucy, or maybe Lucy was her dog's name, but I'm not quite sure. After her mom is sent to jail, she is sent to live with this woman who cares for her. At the woman's house (forgot her name), she gets fed more food than she got with her mother (her mother doesn't get much pay).

Lucy also has a dog. I think that the name was Lucky, but I'm not quite sure.

The cover is the back view of Lucy hugging a dog with black and brown fur. They are staring outside a window, and Lucy is wearing a green shirt. The book was published by Scholastic in 2016-2018, but I think that it was most likely published in 2018. The targeted audience is probably 2nd grade to fourth grade, my cousin was in third grade when I read it to her.

Word count: 20,000-40,000 words. The book was about half-inch to a full inch thick.

Oh, forgot to add something! Lucy and her mother liked to say something like this at bedtime:

> "I love you."
> "I love you too."
> "I love you three."
> "I love you four."
> "I love you more."

The book is written in English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The names are different but the cover and plot appear to match: *[Strays Like Us](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36127483-strays-like-us)* by Cecilia Galante:

> From the moment Fred (never Winifred!) spots a scruffy little mutt
> with sad eyes, she knows she's in big trouble. Toby's in bad shape,
> and Fred longs to rescue him from the old man with the mile-long mean
> streak who lives next door. But Margery—the straight-talking woman who
> is fostering Fred—says going over to their house is against the rules.
>
> And since Fred will only be around until her mother comes to grips
> with her dependence, Fred can't let herself care too deeply. Not about
> Toby or Margery or Delia, a new classmate whose insistent friendship
> surprises Fred at every turn. Because the more Fred lets this loveable
> band of misfits into her heart, the harder it'll be to leave them all
> behind.
>
> In this story of loss and love, acclaimed author Cecilia Galante
> examines life's difficult choices and how a girl plus the dog she
> loves can add up to finding family in the most unlikely places.

[image: front cover (source: Goodreads)]

Comment: Great find! I've edited in a cover image since it so closely matches what the OP describes. One of the Goodreads reviews also mentions "*When Fred's (nee Winfred) mother is arrested at her job in a pharmacy for stealing medication, Fred finds herself an hour from her home in Philadelphia.*"